# How can I copy a formated Excel table to auto-fill a Fillable PDF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba

**2021-11-10**

I created an Excel VBA script to create a table that is in the same format as a fillable tax spreadsheet. I would like to copy the cells from Excel to the fillable tax spreadsheet, but when I try to manually paste the Excel table into the Adobe PDF, it pastes into one cell instead of all the cells. How can I fix this?

Excel Table:

[image: Excel Table]

Fillable PDF (US Tax Form):
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8949.pdf

**2021-11-11**

Thank you Jeorge and Nelson for the detailed responses.

I decided to go the XML route described in Jeorje's post, and I think that I almost have it solved, but I'm running into one last problem. I need to automate the process of importing the XML files into the PDF files, since I will have over 100 pdf files.

**Updates:**

1. I created an Excel VBA script that takes the Excel Table (above) and splits it into several XML files named '<#>_form8949.xml'. I have confirmed this works by manually importing these auto-generated XML files into the pdf form using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
2. I created a Javascript file that automatically duplicates the original empty pdf form and names them '<#>_form8949.pdf'. Now I have a folder with the xml files and the pdf files using the same naming convention (see picture below).
   [image: file system]

3. I created an AutoHotKey script to automatically import the XML files into Adobe Acrobat.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Jeorge and Nelson for the detailed responses.

I decided to go the XML route described in Jeorje's post, and I think that I almost have it solved, but I'm running into one last problem.

**Updates:**

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck for doing what you are asking for. PDF forms take data input ONE field at a time and that's that.

So no pasting a table of values all at once into the form.

However, there are some ways to do what you desire, or what I assume you desire, which is to create the data load in Excel and have it all load into the form.

There is a way to use VBA to transfer the data. You initiate the form by picking a starting field, or having the macro start in field one, even if it then has to move 20 fields to the first entry. Then the macro moves back and forth between the data in Excel and the form fields, copying an Excel field, moving to the form field, placing the data, moving to the next field, going back to Excel and moving to the next field, then repeating until done.

You'd have to write that macro or have it written for you.

Another approach requires a PDF editor to access the form controls. I use Adobe Acrobat X (from years ago). In said program, find how to access the form creation/editing/etc. You are looking for more involved options such as what Acrobat X calls "More Form Options" or might be outright shown as Importing or Exporting form data.

The idea is to open the IRS form, then find the Export control or menu item, and export the form data. This will create an XML file which you can use as a template for an Excel file. This idea is then to have Excel formulas create the filled in .XML file using your data and let you copy and paste the result overtop the exported .XML file. Save that and Import it into the form.

I tested precisely this and it works very nicely. There's a bit of work implementing it in the spreadsheet, mixing each line's text elements with the formula to obtain the data for each line of the .XML file, but it's monkey work:  figure how to do one, then do all the same way. And you can be clever about the text pieces, pasting the bare .XML material into a column and pulling the pieces out via formula, mixing in the data that goes in each field. So, write one formula, copy down, copy and paste over the .XML file, then use your PDF editor to Import the .XML file.

The data, fairly obviously, but probably in the "ought to still be mentioned" category, goes inside tags that look like `<f1_3>HORSE</f1_3>`. (Your data was a picture, so unusable, and "HORSE" is what I picked for the first field in Page 1's body. You'd parse out the `<f1_3>` string, concatenate the data "HORSE" with it, parse out the `</f1_3>` string and concatenate that as well, and you'd have that field's entry. Truth is, since they follow an exact pattern, "f1_3", "f1_4" and so on, and adding a beginning "<" or "</" and an ending ">" to the string is simple, you wouldn't really have to parse anything, just build it using bits and making the numbers before and after the underscore increment as necessary.

String building is an art in Excel that more attention should be paid to.

Make sure everything ended up where expected, fix any goofs, and you're "in."

Form changes from year to year would have to be edited for, but since the IRS likes to be conservative about that (not for your ease, surely, but their own data processing), it should be minor over the years.

In addition, since one is filling things in, "header" info like the first fields at the very top are easy to accommodate as well. Also, arithmetic can be done with the certainty that it is correct, no typos.

What you just can't do without knowledge that eludes ME is to create the .XML file from scratch by saving the Excel file as an .XML file. Tried that, and it requires an XML Schema which just doesn't exist. It won't create one, it won't take the form file into account in any of various ways to create one, and it won't use the Export file as one. In fact, it's just a stupid mess. Maybe someone will read this answer and tell me what I missed.

Further, Acrobat X requires the Import be from an .XML file and not a spreadsheet file or even a CSV. Bummer. Perhaps your chosen PDF editor would not be such a pain? If so, then all the better as familiar tools would do the work from beginning to end, almost.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a script that can sort of copy-and-paste into your PDF via [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

After installing AHK, create a new file with `ahk` extension and put in the following code:

```
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

#IfWinActive f8949.pdf ahk_exe Acrobat.exe

^v::
SetKeyDelay, 75
Clipboard = %Clipboard%
Clipboard := StrReplace(Clipboard, "`r`n", "`t")
SendRaw % Clipboard
return
```

Double click on the `ahk` file and you should see a little green H icon show up in your system tray (my file is named `f8749.ahk`):

[image]

This little script replaces <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> in Adobe Acrobat so that it parses your Clipboard and outputs as keystrokes. Copy from Excel (block select only your data; **don't copy the whole line!** Start with 2 rows of data first), select the first cell in the PDF, and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

The line `SetKeyDelay, 75` may need to be increased if it is missing characters, since Adobe Reader seems to be reading the keys and doesn't output the keystrokes very quickly. You can tweak it lower if your computer is faster and can handle the faster output. You can double click the file or right click the green H icon to reload the script. The first line `#SingleInstance Force` lets you double click the file for fast re-deploy.

The line `#IfWinActive f8949.pdf ahk_exe Acrobat.exe` is dependent on your PDF file to be named `f8949.pdf`. You can change that to be simply `#IfWinActive ahk_exe Acrobat.exe`, but this will end up affecting every instance of Adobe Reader.

At last, when done with the script, right click on your sys tray icon and `Exit` the script.

You can see it in action here:

[image]

The output will mimic whatever formatting you used in Excel. I tested different types of numeric formats (negative vs brackets).